# "UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found" but correct naming?

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, native-code

My native method cannot be found and I cannot solve it.

java code:

```
package org.cocos2dx.cppemptytest;

public class TestJNI {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("cpp_empty_test");
    }
    public native String moveto();
}
```

native code:

```
#include "AppDelegate.h"
#include "platform/android/jni/JniHelper.h"
#include <jni.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "cocos2d.h"

#define  LOG_TAG    "main"
#define  LOGD(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)

using namespace cocos2d;

AppDelegate *pAppDelegate;

void cocos_android_app_init (JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz) {
    LOGD("cocos_android_app_init");
    pAppDelegate = new AppDelegate();
}

extern "C" {

    JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_org_cocos2dx_cppemptytest_TestJNI_moveto
         ( JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz){
        return env->NewStringUTF("default");
    }
}
```

in Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := cpp_empty_test

LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := libcpp_empty_test

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := main.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/AppDelegate.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../Classes \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../extensions \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../.. \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../cocos/editor-support

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := cocos2dx_static

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-module,.)
```

Output gives unsatisfied link error, but my naming is correct I guess. Are there any other reasons why this error occurrs?

```
E/AndroidRuntime(30310): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
Native method not found: 
org.cocos2dx.cppemptytest.TestJNI.moveto:()Ljava/lang/String;
```

Comment: try to make moveto() method in java as static

Comment: @Suvitruf Same error, any other ideas?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? If you did, can you post the solution as I have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your in **Android.mk** to this:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := libcpp_empty_test
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := main.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: thanks, can you explain the difference to the previous .mk? I updated mine above to the full file.

Comment: @user2212461I removed LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME. Does it solve the problem?

Comment: the error still occurs without LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME